# A rebus I've just watched

Tags: rebus, movies

[image][image]

> These two rebuses will give you a clue to what movie I've just watched. Can you guess it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe you watched

> Shrek

The first is

> D (Roman numeral 500) on key = [donkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_(Shrek))

And the second

> <strike>Wi</strike>Fi on A = [Fiona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Fiona)

Comment: You got everything right!